# Adjust column with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

In this example

```
 \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=12.1]}
    A & {sf}\\
    0 & 9887779.1\\
    0 & 9999.1 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

I have previewed too many integers in the table format. This is visible in the output:

[image]

particularly causing the column head awkwardly displaced.

Is there a way to automatically adjust the column to the actual content?

Comment: `[table-format=7.1]`? Why it is necessary for 12 digits?

Comment: @JouleV, imagine we are dealing with many, rapidly changing columns. There is nobody to count digits. Is there no automatic way to adjust?

Comment: SI columns do it automatically to `[table-format=<x>.<x>]` where `<x>` is the largest number of digits in each sides of the dot. In this case it leads to `[table-format=7.7]`. It is useful for many kind of scientific tables. If you want to change it, you have to do manually

Comment: It is not that hard to count the digit anyway. If you have specified the `S` column, the digits will be grouped, and now counting is a simple action and a trivial multiplication

Comment: From page 14 of the `siunitx` documenttion: "The `S` column will attempt to automatically detect material which should be placed before  or  after  a  number,  and  will  maintain  the  alignment  of  the  numerical  data (Table8). " So maybe you are satisfied with the automatic alignment when using an `S` type column without any `table-format`. Other than that I doubt that such an automatic alignment is possible.

Comment: Related: [siunitx Auto-detect table-format in S column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448739/134144)

Comment: @leandriis, when using only `S` the column head gets centred on the decimal point. How to centre the column head then?

Comment: You asked, "Is there a way to automatically adjust the column to the actual content?" Short answer: No. Incidentally, what about your tables causes you to have to "[deal] with many, rapidly changing columns"? Are you maybe dealing with the outcomes of utterly uncontrolled random experiments?

Comment: @Viesturs: Honestly, I tink that you have the following three possibilities: a) use `c` type columns and get centered headers but loose the alignment of numbers relative to theis decimal separator; b) use `S` type columns to align the numbers but loose the centered alignment of the headers; c) use `S` type columns and an  appropriate `table-format` to get the desired alignment while having to manually determine the decimal places.